# Grab correct value from hidden input from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of some parents and under its child. My goal is when I click any of list it will grab its hidden input value but the problem is its grabbing only single value for all items. I am using hidden input id to select items. Whats wrong I am doing here? I also used a class to the input but still not works. Any idea?

```js
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".p").click(function () {
            var z = $("#pid").val();
            alert(z);
        })

        $(".c").click(function () {
            var z = $("#cid").val();
            alert(z);
        })

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Just test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

<div class="List">
    <div class="parents">
        <h4 class="p">
            <a href="#">
                <u>
                 <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="1">
                    <b>Parents text 1</b>
                </u>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="child">
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0001">
                        <b>Child text 1</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0002">
                        <b>Child text 2</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parents">
        <h4 class="p">
            <a href="#">
                <u>
                 <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="2">
                    <b>Parents text 2</b>
                </u>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="child">
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0003">
                        <b>Child text 1</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0004">
                        <b>Child text 2</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ID should be unique use class instead with this context like `$(this).find('pid')` or `$(this).find('cid')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the same id for all the fields so whenever it will trigger click event the value with id at first place will be alerted. You have to find the id within the `.p` or `.c` class and that can be achieved by using `$(this).find()`

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to refer current instance of element

```js
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".p").click(function () {
            var z = $(this).find("#pid").val();
            alert(z);
        })

        $(".c").click(function () {
            var z = $(this).find("#cid").val();
            alert(z);
        })

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Just test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

<div class="List">
    <div class="parents">
        <h4 class="p">
            <a href="#">
                <u>
                 <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="1">
                    <b>Parents text 1</b>
                </u>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="child">
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0001">
                        <b>Child text 1</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0002">
                        <b>Child text 2</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parents">
        <h4 class="p">
            <a href="#">
                <u>
                 <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="2">
                    <b>Parents text 2</b>
                </u>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="child">
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0003">
                        <b>Child text 1</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0004">
                        <b>Child text 2</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: don't suggest to go with duplicate IDs.

Comment: I just mentioned what he is missing. I never mentioned to use duplicate IDs :p. And yes he should not use duplicate IDs

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the id within the .p class, also ids are supposed to be unique, you can use class instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".p").click(function () {
            var z = $(this).find("#pid").val();
            alert(z);
        })

        $(".c").click(function () {
            var z = $(this).find("#cid").val();
            alert(z);
        })

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Just test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

<div class="List">
    <div class="parents">
        <h4 class="p">
            <a href="#">
                <u>
                 <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="1">
                    <b>Parents text 1</b>
                </u>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="child">
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0001">
                        <b>Child text 1</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0002">
                        <b>Child text 2</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parents">
        <h4 class="p">
            <a href="#">
                <u>
                 <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="2">
                    <b>Parents text 2</b>
                </u>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="child">
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0003">
                        <b>Child text 1</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
            <h6 class="c">
                <a href="#">
                    <u>
                     <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="0004">
                        <b>Child text 2</b>
                    </u>
                </a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <script>

       
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get it by its value something like this

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  a = $('select > option:selected').text();
  $('ul>li').css('visibility', 'hidden')
  $("ul > li[value='" + a + "']").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

```css
.Hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='Hidden' value='grab1'>grab1</li>
  <li class='Hidden' value='grab2'>grab2</li>
  <li class='Hidden' value='grab3'>grab3</li>
  <li class='Hidden' value='grab4'>grab4</li>
  <li class='Hidden' value='grab5'>grab5</li>
  <li class='Hidden' value='grab6'>grab6</li>
</ul>
<select>

<option>grab1</option>
<option>grab2</option>
<option>grab3</option>
<option>grab4</option>
<option>grab5</option>
<option>grab6</option>
</select>
```